# matching names across multiple lists

Tags: python, list

the following code is what I've tried to do so far:

```
import json

uids = {'483775843796': '"jared trav"','483843796': '"azu jared"', '483843996': '"hello azu"', '44384376': '"bitten virgo"', '48384326': '"bitten hello"', '61063868': '"charm feline voxela derp virgo"', '11136664': '"jessica"', '11485423': '"yukkixxtsuki"', '10401438': '"howen"', '29176667': '"zaku ramba char"', '36976082': '"bulma zelda dame prince"', '99661300': '"voxela"', '76923817': '"juniperrose"', '16179876': '"gnollfighter"', '45012369': '"pianist fuzz t travis blunt trav ttttttttttttttttttyt whole ryann lol tiper cuz"', '62797501': '"asriel"', '73647929': '"voxela"', '95019796': '"dao daoisms"', '70094978': '"mort"', '16233382': '"purrs"', '89270209': '"apocalevie waify"', '42873540': '"tear slash peaches attitude maso lyra juvia innocent"', '61284894': '"pup"', '68487075': '"ninja"', '66451758': '"az"', '23492247': '"vegeta"', '77980169': '"virus"'}

def _whois(string):
    a = []
    for i in uids:
        i = json.loads(uids[i])
        i = i.split()
        if string in i:
            a += i
    for i in uids:
        i = json.loads(uids[i])
        i = i.split()
        if bool(set(i) & set(a)) == True:
            a += i
    return list(set(a))

def whois(string):
    a = []
    ret = _whois(string)
    for i in ret:
        a += _whois(i)
    return list(set(a))

print(whois("charm"))
```

I am trying to match a search term with accounts that share an id with the term in it, and then match each of those other accounts that are with the id to other accounts on other ids and so on and basically see all of the linked accounts that start from a single term.

For example, if I searched "charm" it would return: "charm feline voxela derp virgo bitten hello" from the example uids above.

After a certain way down the line of connected accounts it stops matching. How would I successfully do this so that it matches all accounts potentially infinitely?

Comment: edit: fixed code and corrected identical dict keys

Comment: Why do you feel that your code is incomplete? Have you tested it? In which case does it not work correctly?

Comment: i just tested it again and after a certain way down the line of connected accounts it stops matching

Comment: Please show a [mre].

Comment: i edited it to show that if you search for "charm" it stops at trav. example: whois('charm') returns ['derp', 'hello', 'virgo', 'jared', 'charm', 'azu', 'bitten', 'voxela', 'feline'] when it should return "trav" and so on as well

Comment: so its now reproducible

Comment: When executing the code, nothing happens.

Comment: running it in idle shell works for me. maybe i need to look in to advanced matching algorithms?

Comment: Apparently you are running more code than you have shown here, otherwise there will be no output at all. This code just defines a dictionary and two functions but does not call them.

Comment: i call the "whois" function in python idle and i added import json to the code

Comment: example: whois('charm')

Comment: My first suggestion would be to eliminate all of the json stuff.  It is just making the code more opaque.  Simplify by just assigning uid = {'483775843796': ['jared', 'trav'], ...  Or actually, since you really want sets eventually uid =  {'483775843796': {'jared', 'trav'}, ...  Then with all of the reformatting removed the logic of what your trying to do might be cleaer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think i got it to work:

```
import json

terms = {'4837759863453450996': '"mamma riyoken"','4833480984509580996': '"mamma heika"','483775980980996': '"nemo heika"','4867568843796': '"control nemo"','4956775843796': '"t control"','483775843796': '"jared trav"','483843796': '"azu jared"', '483843996': '"hello azu"', '44384376': '"bitten virgo"', '48384326': '"bitten hello"', '61063868': '"charm feline voxela derp virgo"', '11136664': '"jessica"', '11485423': '"yukkixxtsuki"', '10401438': '"howen"', '29176667': '"zaku ramba char"', '36976082': '"bulma zelda dame prince"', '99661300': '"voxela"', '76923817': '"juniperrose"', '16179876': '"gnollfighter"', '45012369': '"pianist fuzz t travis blunt trav ttttttttttttttttttyt whole ryann lol tiper cuz"', '62797501': '"asriel"', '73647929': '"voxela"', '95019796': '"dao daoisms"', '70094978': '"mort"', '16233382': '"purrs"', '89270209': '"apocalevie waify"', '42873540': '"tear slash peaches attitude maso lyra juvia innocent"', '61284894': '"pup"', '68487075': '"ninja"', '66451758': '"az"', '23492247': '"vegeta"', '77980169': '"virus"'}

def _search(string):
    a = []
    for i in terms:
        i = json.loads(terms[i])
        i = i.split()
        if string in i:
            a += i
    return list(set(a))

def search(string):
    a = []
    a.append(string)
    while True:
        l = len(a)
        for n in a:
            a += _search(n)
            a = list(set(a))
        if l == len(a):
            break
    return a
    
            
print(search("charm"))
```

Comment: edit removed superfluous code

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ids = {'483775843796': '"jared trav"','483843796': '"azu jared"', '483843996': '"hello azu"', '44384376': '"bitten virgo"', '48384326': '"bitten hello"', '61063868': '"charm feline voxela derp virgo"', '11136664': '"jessica"', '11485423': '"yukkixxtsuki"', '10401438': '"howen"', '29176667': '"zaku ramba char"', '36976082': '"bulma zelda dame prince"', '99661300': '"voxela"', '76923817': '"juniperrose"', '16179876': '"gnollfighter"', '45012369': '"pianist fuzz t travis blunt trav ttttttttttttttttttyt whole ryann lol tiper cuz"', '62797501': '"asriel"', '73647929': '"voxela"', '95019796': '"dao daoisms"', '70094978': '"mort"', '16233382': '"purrs"', '89270209': '"apocalevie waify"', '42873540': '"tear slash peaches attitude maso lyra juvia innocent"', '61284894': '"pup"', '68487075': '"ninja"', '66451758': '"az"', '23492247': '"vegeta"', '77980169': '"virus"'}

def find_word(word,dict):
  for i,j in dict.items():
    if word.lower() in j.lower():
      print(i,j)

find_word('jared', ids)
```

Result:

```
483775843796 "jared trav"
483843796 "azu jared"
```

Comment: i want it to then repeat the process with azu and trav and so on until everything connected is found

Comment: Not sure to understand. I've also read the comments below your question but can't figure out what you're trying to achieve. Could you be more explicit? Write down your expected result.

Comment: "if I searched "charm" it would return: "charm feline voxela derp virgo bitten hello" from the example uids above." What's the logic to return "bitten hello" too in this case???

Comment: basically if the function you posted was repeated over and over again with every word found until there were no more matches

Comment: Still unclear, If i start like my example with "jared", I then have 2 results giving me 2 new words ("trav" and "azu"), which one should be the next? Because if I continue with "trav" or "azu" I won't go the same path.

Comment: i guess i was trying to explain this without background context; the search matches accounts that share a similar id, then finds the accounts on other ids that are the same if they get a new id and lists those accounts as well and so on. i got it working in my answer.